# Rsync doen'st backup mounted (encfs) subdirectories

Tags: encryption, rsync

I'm using rsync since years to backup my computer to my external drive.
The command I'm using looks like this:

```
sudo rsync -rltDvHiPb --backup-dir=/media/extern/backup --delete --ignore-errors --exclude .thumbnails/ --exclude .encrypted/ --stats --log-file=/media/extern/backup/rsync_linux.log /home /etc /var /media/extern/Linux'
```

Like you can see, there is a exclusion for the directory .encrypted, which contains my documents encrypted with encfs. I mount this directory with

```
encfs .encrypted ~/Documents
```

When running the rsync command after the mounting of the decrypted data, the folder ~/Documents will not be backuped. Does someone have an idea why?

/edit: I found out, that it is related to user rights... When performing the rsync with the same user that mounted the encfs directory, it is working... Can it be, that mounts can only be seen by users that mounted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmh, I found a sulation that works for me.

man encfs is saying (under --public) " By default, all FUSE based filesystems are visible only to the user who mounted them".

So one option would be to use the --public. But a better idea is to use fuse parameters to allow root access.

Therefore two steps must be done:

1. edit with root rights /etc/fuse.conf and add/uncomment the line user_allow_others
2. pass the fuse option 'allow_root' with encfs to fuse:

   encfs -o allow_root .encrypted ~/Documents

With this it is working :-)